# Workspaces are copy of default workspace

Tags: gnome, 14.10, workspaces

I am having trouble with workspaces. All workspaces are exact copy of the default one, i.e., I can't start a blank workspace and do something new. There are no blank workspaces, all of them are replicas of current workspace and if I try switching I only get back to where I was. [image: Here is an image]

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 and running GNOME Shell 3.12.2. Note: I have enabled workspaces using GNOME Tweak Tool.

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked "workspaces only on primary display" in the gnome tweak tool and it fixed it for me. Maybe that will work for you too.

Answer (score -1):

[image]You need to set Workspaces to be on. Go to `All Settings`> `Appearance`> and confirm that `Enable workspaces` is checked.

Comment: Since the GNOME, OP will probably need GNOME Tweak Tool to do that.

Comment: @muru Crikey, have matters changed so much from 14.04 to 14.10?

Comment: Not from 14.04 to 14.10, but GNOME Control Centre doesn't have an Appearance section.

Comment: I have already set Workspaces to on using GNOME tweak tool.